# Trying to Add dollar sign to Display String // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to edit my javascript code to display a $ before my values, but I am recieving the error code in my console as :" Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment "

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

```
    <!--//4. Display Results  MAKE IT A STRING DISPLAY-->
    displayString = "Base Pay " + "$" + basePayAmount.toFixed(2) + "<br />" +
                        "Overtime Pay " + "$" + overtimePayAmount.toFixed(2) = "<br/>" +
                        "Total Pay " + "$" + totalPayAmount.toFixed(2);

        document.getElementById("divDisplay").innerHTML = displayString;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
… overtimePayAmount.toFixed(2) = "<br/>"
```

You're trying to assign a value to the result of concatenating a bunch of strings.

Possibly that `=` should be another `+`.